# Different line spacing depending on font encoding

Tags: terminal, fonts, xorg, unicode, truetype-fonts

Historically, I've been using [Monotype Courier New](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_%28typeface%29#Courier_New) as my *XTerm* font (it displays well both Cyrillic characters and [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)). When migrating from legacy **KOI8-R** to **UTF-8** locale, I've noticed a change in the inter-line spacing (or [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading)), which made *Courier New* no longer suitable for terminals.

Here's how my XTerm used to look in `ru_RU.KOI8-R` locale (12pt Courier New):

[image]

Here's how it looks now (`ru_RU.UTF-8`, 12pt again, character width is the same, but note the increased leading, vertical box-drawing charaters form a double "dashed" line):

[image]

Apparently, XTerm is not the only application affected. Basically, all programs using Core X11 Fonts exhibit the same behaviour. Take a look at `xfontsel` displaying different encodings of the same font:

**KOI8-R**:

[image]

**ISO 10646-1** (which stands for Unicode):

[image]

Interestingly, Courier New seems to be the only monospaced font affected. Other fonts, like `-misc-freemono-*`, have the same leading regardless of the encoding.

Now, **the question**:

Is there any way I can enforce the particular leading for a particular font? Should I look into the *FreeType* library? Or *Xft*? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution might be to use the `scaleHeight` resource in the
`.Xresources` file,
[described](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm#Adjust_line_spacing)
as:

> **Adjust line spacing**
>
> Lines of text can sometimes be too close together, or they may appear
>   to be too widely spaced. For one example, using DejaVu Sans Mono, the
>   low underscore glyph may butt against CJK glyphs or the cursor block
>   in the line below. Line spacing, called leading by typographers, can
>   be adjusted with the following resource, for example to widen the
>   spacing:
>
> ```
> XTerm.scaleHeight: 1.01
> ```
>
> Valid values for range from 0.9 to 1.5, with 1.0 being the default.

I would suggest to try and see if the minimum is enough:

```
XTerm.scaleHeight: 0.9
```

You could try to go below that, if necessary and if XTerm will accept it.

Comment: Thank you — I’m aware of the `scaleHeight` resource. It works... to an extent, w/o providing the perfect picture I used to have in earlier versions of X11. Basically, this is a regression in the core X font subsystem, which will never be fixed. I personally ended up using client-side rather than server-side fonts in XTerm (those get rendered correctly).